# Logic doesn't find the sound library on a external drive

Tags: logic

For some reason Logic can't seem to find the sound library I saved on an external drive and everytime I open it, the following window opens prompting me to download all essential sounds:

[image: window when I open Logic]

But somehow Logic seems to know where the library is, because when I try to relocate it, this window opens, showing that the current file location is my drive.

[image: window when i try to relocate the files]

Does anyone know a solution or has had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but I deleted all files and started Logic again to download the essential sounds. Then relocated them to the drive and installed the whole library again.